# Edit strings of variable length

Tags: c#, .net

How can I take only the number from strings in this format:

```
       "####-somestring"
       "###-someotherstring"
       "######-anotherstring"
```

Comment: check the MaskedTextBox control http://en.csharp-online.net/MaskedTextBox

Comment: you can still copy & paste non allowed characters into the textbox without additional validating, so you can just take a normal textbox and validate it yourself. Also, there is no mention of a control in the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
int.parse( Regex.match(String, @"\d+").value)
```

Comment: Of course, you'd need a closing ", but this gets my upvote.  You'd need to account for no-match situations too.

Comment: \d would do it just habit. you don't need the () since i'm not using a capture or a group

Answer (score 3):

```
string s =  "####-somestring";
string digits = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("-") - 1);
int parsedDigits = int.Parse(digits);
```

for more complicated combinations you'd have to use Regex.

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure they will always have a '-' in them you can use the string split function.

```
string cutThisUp = "######-anotherstring";
string[] parts = cutThisUp.Split(Convert.ToChar("-"));
int numberPart = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
```

Comment: Just FYI, You don't need to call `Convert.ToChar("-")`; use single quotes to indicate a `char` rather than a `string` (so: `cutThisUp.Split('-')`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following:

```
string s = "####-somestring";
return Regex.Match(s, "(\d)+").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option: split on the `-` character and try to parse the first item in the resulting array (this is the same as nbushnell's suggestion, with a little added safety):

```
public bool TryGetNumberFromString(string s, out int number) {
    number = default(int);

    string[] split = s.Split('-');
    if (split.Length < 1)
        return false;

    return int.TryParse(split[0], out number);
}
```